# Is it possible to update bower dependencies using grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, dependencies, task, package, bower

I’m using grunt to develop a website, and was wondering if it’s possible to **update bower dependencies** in my project within my 'build' grunt task—so that when I build a production version of my project, everything is up–to–date?

Obviously, I know I could just execute `bower update` before `grunt build:prod`, but it would be one less step every time.

Just curious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grunt has this task called [grunt-bower-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower-task) which can help you manage bower dependencies. Use the official grunt documentation to go through the details.

Answer (score 0):

Found one possible solution:

I guess I could use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to automate running the `bower update` command in a shell…

Just wondering if this is the most logical/sophisticated way of doing it. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found a good solution—I’ll post it in case it’s of use to someone…

The [**grunt-bower-install-simple**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower-install-simple) plugin allows you to update bower dependencies from a grunt task by setting the `command` option to `update` like so:

```
"bower-install-simple": {

    options: {
        color: true,
        directory: "src/bower_components"
    }

    "prod": {
        options: {
            command: update,
            production: true
    }
}
```